# How to fix an invalid CFBundleVersion error?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I know why this error occurred but the issue dont get resolved. How can I fix this error thrown below?

```
Xcode build done.                                           139.7s
Unable to install /Users/ljsharp/Downloads/gsl_dictionary/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on 69287A0D-7119-413E-AF7E-C608ADF7B106. This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
    Failed to install the requested application
    The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
  Command: xcrun simctl install 69287A0D-7119-413E-AF7E-C608ADF7B106 /Users/ljsharp/Downloads/gsl_dictionary/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited
```

[image]

**Info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>gsl_dictionary</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
```

Is there a way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in info.plist

```
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
```